# Parse line to get N values

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I need help to get the N dates that could be in this line:

> "vmsnapshot":"Snapshot 1 created on dom ago  5 11:03:09 -04 2018.
>   Info: OFF Snapshot solicitado según INC000001850649. Snapshot 2
>   created on dom ago 26 02:44:44 -03 2018. Info: OFF
>   user-VCD-snapshot-ab221cb8-539d-456a-8732-8500ec7fefa6-. "

I just need to rescue the dates, I have some ideas like adding it to an arrangement, but maybe there is something more optimal to do it.

Example result :
- ago 5 2018
- ago 26 2018

Thank you

Comment: Be clear. Are you asking to extract the dates from data represented as a string? What have you tried? Asking for a solution to even simple things is generally not going to get you much traction here. Hint: a naive approach is regular expressions: http://regex101.com

Comment: @Manuel welcome to SO! What programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expressions as it is usually the best approach for that kind of tasks.

In your case it will be something like this (JavaScript example)

https://regex101.com/r/nJ9JfD/1/

Group 1 will capture `ago <1 or more digits>`

Group 2 will capture `<space><any four digits>`

Combining result of those two groups will give you the expected output.